# How to create Description List?

Tags: html, css, frontend

```
text   1

text   text: 321
       text: 123
```

How to create such a sheet, according to new standards + responsive.
Without the use of float, etc. ?

This is my option.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e376Lwdf/)

But I thinks it is not very optimal.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please write properly what you've tried so far, what's your actual/expected output, etc.

Comment: @AjayDabas I updated question.

Comment: Grid is the latest syntax for this, but the problem is that it doesn't support multiple browsers, therefore I think the best way is to use flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a [grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  height:90vh;
}
div:nth-child(1):not(.container){
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
div:nth-child(2){
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
div:nth-child(3){
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
div:nth-child(4){
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>item</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>
    <ul>Foo
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```